# Finding maximum product of 13 adjacent digits in 10,000 digit number

Tags: python

Can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code (Project Euler problem 8). I want to find the maximum product of 13 adjacent digits in the 10,000 digit number below, and I'm getting the wrong answer.

```
my_list = list('7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450')

for i in range(1000):
    my_list[i] = int(my_list[i])

previous_product = 1
for x in range(13):
  previous_product *= my_list[x]
current_product = previous_product*my_list[13]/my_list[0]

for i in range(1, 987):
  if current_product > previous_product:
    maximum_product = current_product
  previous_product = current_product
  if my_list[i]==0:
    current_product = 1
    for x in range(13):
      current_product *= my_list[i+x+1]
  else:
    current_product = previous_product*my_list[i+x+1]/my_list[i]

print(maximum_product)
```

Edit: Solved! maximum_product was defined wrongly... it takes on the value of the most recent "current product" that happens to be greater than the previous product, not necessarily the largest product.

Correct, albeit not-super-efficient code:

```
   my_list = list('7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450')

for i in range(1000):
    my_list[i] = int(my_list[i])

previous_product = 1
for x in range(13):
  previous_product *= my_list[x]
current_product = previous_product*my_list[13]/my_list[0]

large_products = []

for i in range(1, 987):
  if current_product > previous_product:
    large_products.append(current_product)
  previous_product = current_product
  if my_list[i]==0:
    current_product = 1
    for x in range(13):
      current_product *= my_list[i+x+1]
  else:
    current_product = previous_product*my_list[i+x+1]/my_list[i]

print(max(large_products))
```

Comment: This question probably belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why not split on `0` and handle each piece separately, each with vastly simpler logic? Also, if this is Python 3 you need to be aware of `/` vs. `//`.

Comment: **In what way** is your code not working?

Comment: @Teodor: CR is for _working code_: please read [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @DSM Thanks for the reference.

Comment: There's a bug in how you handle 0 because of the counting. I can't quite pinpoint it exactly though

Comment: @martineau it gives the wrong answer: 313528320.0 instead of 23514624000

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked why your approach doesn't work but you can easily solve this with:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

my_int_list = [int(char) for char in my_list]

max(map(lambda *x: reduce(operator.mul, x), 
        my_int_list[0:], 
        my_int_list[1:], 
        my_int_list[2:], 
        my_int_list[3:], 
        my_int_list[4:], 
        my_int_list[5:], 
        my_int_list[6:], 
        my_int_list[7:], 
        my_int_list[8:], 
        my_int_list[9:], 
        my_int_list[10:], 
        my_int_list[11:], 
        my_int_list[12:]))
```

In case this takes up too much memory you could also use `itertools.islice` instead of the direct slicing with `[idx:]`.

Comment: yeah man, awesome solution, in fact you can improve it with the islice and another map

Comment: `max(map(lambda *x: reduce(operator.mul, x), 
        *map(lambda x: islice(my_int_list, x, None), xrange(13))))`

Comment: Or this: `max(reduce(mul, xs[i : i + 13], 1) for i in range(0, len(xs) - 13 + 1))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of your sliding window idea, modified so that it only applies to strings which contain no zeros:

```
def max_product(s,k):
    s = [int(d) for d in s]
    p = 1
    for d in s[:k]:
        p *= d
    m = p
    for i,d in enumerate(s[k:]):
        p *= d
        p //= s[i]
        if p > m: m = p
    return p
```

In the above `s` is a string of nonzero digits of length at least `k` (`k = 13` in your problem). It returns the largest product of `k` successive digits. The subtlety is in the way enumerate works. When you use `enumerate` on `s[k:]` the index, `i`, starts at `0` -- which is exactly the factor that you want to remove in the first pass through that loop.

To apply this to

```
data = '7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'
```

First split into chunks which contain no zeros and are at least 13 digits long:

```
chunks = [s for s in data.split('0') if len(s) >= 13]
```

There are 24 such chunks. To get the overall max, just take the max of the max of each chunk:

```
print(max(max_product(s,13) for s in chunks))
```

which does indeed print `23514624000`

Answer (score 0):

Your current code isn't working because it seems to be based on the wrong plan
-- or at least on a plan that I do not fully understand. Here's a different way
to think about the algorithm.

Imagine we have this number: `7316717`. And we are looking for the maximum
product of 3 adjacent digits. We could solve the problem as follows. I'm
hard-coding the result from each step, but you should be able to write Python
code to compute each part.

- Find all adjacent 3-digit sequences:

  ```
  seqs = [731, 316, 167, 671, 717]
  ```
- Compute their products:

  ```
  products = [21, 18, 42, 42, 49]
  ```
- Find their maximum.

  ```
  answer = max(products)
  ```

Comment: OP's approach is have a sliding window of 13 digits, which s/he updates by multiplying by the next number to enter the window and dividing by the number to leave the window

Comment: @user3080953 I see. Well, that could work, but it's likely to be tricky because one would need to have some additional logic to handle zeros: when one enters the sliding window, your running-product becomes zero (that's easy), but when a zero leaves the window, you need to recompute the running product. And there could be multiple zeros within the window. Sounds bug-prone to me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked your code and in which way it won't work.

But an easy way to solve your problem, is generating all the possibile slices with 13 adjacent numbers from your input data then find the product of their elements then find the maximum product of them all.

Here is a way to do it:

```
data = '7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'

def product(a):
    prod = 1
    for k in a:
        prod *= int(k)
    return prod

def max_adjacent_number(data, suit=13):
    return max(product(data[k:k+suit]) for k in range(len(data)) if '0' not in data[k:k+suit])


from time import time
start = time()
val = max_adjacent_number(data)
elapsed = time() - start
print("Solution: {0} \telapsed: {1:.5f}ms".format(val, elapsed*1000))
```

Output:

```
# Best time
Solution: 23514624000   elapsed: 1.31226ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code efficiency using list comprehension like this:

```
import time
n = str(x) #x is the long number
a = time.time()
result = max(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, map(int, n[i:i+13])) for i in xrange(len(n)-12) if '0' not in n[i:i+13])
b = time.time()
print "Maximum adjacent numbers product: %d" % result
print "Time taken:", (b-a)*1000, "ms"
```

Output:

```
Maximum adjacent numbers product: 23514624000
Time taken: 4.34899330139 ms
```